# Distribution of $X+X^2$ if $X\sim U[0,1]$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ be a continuous uniform r.v. on $[0,1]$. What do we know about the distribution of the polynomial transformation $Y=a_1 X+a_2 X^2+\cdots+a_k X^k$, for $k>1$?

For example, if $k=2$, $a_2<0$ and $-a_1/a_2>1$, then $f(X)=a_1 X+ a_2 X^2$ is a monotone transformation of $X$. But what is the density of $f(X)$?

Comment: What have you tried? For example, what would be the distribution of just $X^2$ ?

Comment: In the quadratic case why not complete the square and go from there?

Comment: I believe you should find CDF of $f(X)$. It may be tiresome, but it should lead to the goal.

Comment: If $g(x)=x+x^2$ with $x \in [0,1]$ then $g^{-1}(y)=\frac{\sqrt{4y+1}-1}{2}$ for $y \in [0,2]$

Comment: The function $f(x) =  \sum_{i=1}^k a_i x^i$ is monotone for $x\in[0,1]$ as in your example for $k=2$?